# Vibration.vibrate works on android but the same code does not work on IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, vibration

Trying to implement a filler word detector for which any instance of 'like' said, the phone vibrate. I use speech to text API and get the text and vibrate when 'like' is detected and it works on Android.

```html
class _RecognizeContent extends StatelessWidget {
    RichText processText() {
    //loops through the text string given by API
    if (filler_word_instances.containsKey(curr_word)) {
        if (!filler_word_instances[curr_word].contains(i) && recognizing && !recognizeStart) {
            Vibration.vibrate(); //---> This doesnt work
            filler_word_instances[curr_word].add(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `HapticFeedback`? It doesn't require a plugin and works on both android and ios

Here is a [how to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2Iv3mMhhF8)

Comment: yup, I have! Unfortunately, HapticFeedback and Vibration both only work for onPressed but I wanted to have it outside of onPressed. For example, when x = 'hi' then vibrate

Comment: I have it working outside of an onPressed statement. Is there something that says that it can only be used as onPressed?